# Rails 4 Enum Map only partial list of all enums

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have an enum in Rails 4 with 60 different values that are coded out in my model. I am trying to divide those enums into different select menus. Currently, I have the following code:

```
          <%= f.select :termenum, Price.termenums.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] },
                        {:include_blank => ''}, class: "form-control" %><br>
```

which displays all of them. Is there a way to have only the first 10 in this select dropdown and then another 10 in another select drop down. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined how. My method was repetitive but still effective. I created a list in the model. COLOR = {"X"=> 14} that matched the enums. Then, I used the select tag in the form with options_for_select(Price::COLOR.map {...} to specify. It seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each_slice` to build the groups.

```
<% i = 0 %>
<%= Price.termenums.each_slice(1) do |enums_slice| %>
  <%= f.select "termenum_#{i += 1}", Price.termenums.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] },
                        {:include_blank => ''}, class: "form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've been playing around with this. It looks like Rails only takes the post data from the last select box in the form. You'd have to give them different names, I'm guessing, and somehow have Rails grab the non-blank value from whatever select element contains it. One problem is how Rails would handle having a value selected in more than one select element.